# The figures compiled in PDF are not the same as what I did in R

Tags: r, plot, latex, knitr

I'm new to creating documents with knitr and Latex, and I use `knitr` to write an econometric report. In this report I need to use some figures to show the results and analyse them. For some figures, when I run the codes in R I got the right one, but when I compiled it into PDF, the figure changed a lot.

There is no error in log, and I have already changed the default weave option to 'knitr'. I'll show you an example of issue below.

Here is the right graph which I got in R:

[image: the right graph in R]

But after compiling in PDF, I got this wrong graph:

[image: the wrong graph in pdf]

Does someone can tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Looks like the data used was actually different. Please check whether the working directory is set correctly. Maybe the date source is not the same in your interactive session and when compiling the document.

Comment: yea that may be the case, I have to check it, such a silly fault... anyway thanks!